# Add rows to a table in rust (code may not be safe?)

Tags: beginner, rust

I'm trying to implement a sql-like in-memory database.

Here is my code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum DataPoint {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f64),
    Text(String),
    Null,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Table {
    name: String,
    rows: Vec<Vec<DataPoint>>,
    cols: Vec<(String, DataPoint)>,
}

impl Table {
    //insert a row into the table
    //returns a bool indicating success
    fn insert_into(&mut self, mut data: Vec<DataPoint>, mut cols_arg: Vec<String>) -> bool {
        // cols_arg is optional. if omitted (len 0) assume data is in the order of columns in the table
        if cols_arg.len() == 0 {
            for (i, _) in data.iter().enumerate() {
                // if these aren't the same data type we fail
                if !(std::mem::discriminant(&data[i]) == std::mem::discriminant(&self.cols[i].1) ||
                    std::mem::discriminant(&data[i]) == std::mem::discriminant(&DataPoint::Null)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            self.rows.push(data);
            return true;
        } else {

            // data to insert and columns to insert into must be the same length
            if data.len() != cols_arg.len() { return false; }
            //temporary vec to hold our row before we're ready to send it off
            let mut out: Vec<DataPoint> = Vec::new();
            for (name, dt) in &self.cols {
                out.push(loop {
                    let i = 0;

                    //if we've consumed everything
                    if cols_arg.len() == 0 {
                        break DataPoint::Null;
                    }
                    // if we've found the correct column
                    if cols_arg[i] == *name {
                        // if these aren't the same data type we fail
                        if !(std::mem::discriminant(&data[i]) == std::mem::discriminant(&dt) ||
                            std::mem::discriminant(&data[i]) == std::mem::discriminant(&DataPoint::Null)) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        //remove the line from the columns list
                        cols_arg.remove(i);
                        //remove and break with the data
                        break data.remove(i);
                    }


                    //I think this is probably bad, right?
                    let i = i + 1;

                    //If we've gone through everything then they didn't specify a value for this column
                    if i >= cols_arg.len() {
                        //so break with null
                        break DataPoint::Null;
                    }
                });
            }

            // if we didn't get to all of them then fail out
            if data.len() != 0 || cols_arg.len() != 0 {
                return false;
            }

            self.rows.push(out);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut first_table = Table {
        name: String::from("First table"),
        rows: Vec::new(),
        // this also seems bad, the 0 doesn't mean anything, all that matters is the variant (not the value)
        cols: vec![(String::from("id"), DataPoint::Int(0))],
    };


    // this works
    println!("{:?}", first_table);
    first_table.insert_into(vec![DataPoint::Int(10)], vec![String::from("id")]);
    println!("{:?}", first_table);

    // this "fails" (the intended behavior)-- nothing is inserted because the data is the wrong type for the column we're
    // trying to insert it into
    first_table.insert_into(vec![DataPoint::Float(10.1)], vec![String::from("id")]);
    println!("{:?}", first_table);

    // this fails (again intended behavior) because we're inserting more value than columns to insert into
    first_table.insert_into(vec![DataPoint::Int(11), DataPoint::Int(12)], vec![String::from("id")]);
    println!("{:?}", first_table);


    // also works with tables with many columns
    let mut second_table = Table {
        name: String::from("Second table"),
        rows: Vec::new(),
        cols: vec![(String::from("id"), DataPoint::Int(0)), (String::from("name"), DataPoint::Text(String::from("")))],
    };

    second_table.insert_into(vec![DataPoint::Int(123)], vec![String::from("id")]);
    println!("{:?}", second_table);

    second_table.insert_into(vec![DataPoint::Int(123), DataPoint::Text(String::from("John Doe"))],
                             vec![String::from("id"), String::from("name")]);

    println!("{:?}", second_table);

    // we can also omit the column names
    second_table.insert_into(vec![
        DataPoint::Int(456),
        DataPoint::Text(String::from("Alice Smith"))
    ],
                             vec![]);

    println!("{:?}", second_table)
}
```

I've decided to go with a variable-length for my rows because I want to (at a later date) be able to have users add columns at runtime. The idea is that if a column is added later then all rows will have <= the maximum number of rows.

The input data for the `insert_into` function is (loosely) structured like an [INSERT INTO statement in SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

The way this code works is it loops through all the columns in the table, and then for each column, it loops through all the (unconsumed) data-to-insert. If the names match, it inserts the data given, if not, it inserts null.

What specifically concerns me here is that `data` and `cols_arg` aren't, as far as the compiler knows, related. This seems bad because the compiler can't guarantee validity here. (Also, the way I'm handling the innermost for-style `loop` seems wrong).